# Add query to range of URLs

Tags: url, translate

I want to add the query **#googtrans(nl|en)** to all URLs containing **/en/**

http://example.nl/en/ always needs to be http://example.nl/en/#googtrans(nl|en)

Sub URLs like *example.nl/en/uncategorized/nieuws/* always need to be *example.nl/en/uncategorized/nieuws/#googtrans(nl|en)*

Maybe useful: whenever /en/ is in the URL, I have li class="lang-en" as "lang-en active", but I don't know if that can help.

The goal is to automatically run Google Translate when English pages are loaded.

Tried through **.htaccess** by adding:

`RedirectMatch ^/en/(.*)$ example.nl/en/$1#googtrans(nl|en)`

But I am getting too many redirects error. Also tried with jquery but my code doesn't work on the url itself:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('li.lang-en.active') { 
        $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "#googtrans(nl|en)”); 
    }) 
});
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Fruitless efforts. Tried through .htaccess by adding RedirectMatch ^/en/(.*)$ example.nl/en/$1#googtrans(nl|en) But I am getting too many redirects error. Also tried with jquery but my code doesn't work on the url itself: $(document).ready(function () { $('li.lang-en.active') { $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "#googtrans(nl|en)”); }) });

Answer (score 0):

After many trial & errors (it wouldn't work through .htaccess I managed to fix it by:

```
<script>
if (document.location.pathname.indexOf("/en/") == 0) {
    window.location.hash = "#googtrans/nl/en";
}
</script>
```